# Building REST API - separate requests

Tags: api, rest

I am building an API and am a little unsure whether it would be better to have a request that brings back all information relating to a resource, or just bring back info separately according to tasks that need carrying out.  For example, I have a messages resource and am struggling to decide whether to bring back all message information in one go.  OR have a separate request for unread messages, a separate request for a list of messages and another request for a single message.

What is the proper way?  I am tempted to keep them all separate but then worrya bout having to do too many requests.

Answer (score 1):

Stop worrying and just **do**.

I like to keep things separate in the beginning, and at some point, I realise that *request x* always followed by *request y*, so I'll just merge those two. You won't know what you'll need until you're working on it...

Comment: Just wanting to plan rather than dive in and end up having to recode.

Comment: IMHO, reducing amount of code is called _progress_. That said, you **really** can't go wrong with either. However stop coding, and thinking a bunch of _what ifs_ doesn't get the job done. And you'll need to accept that recode is just facts of life (of a developer). Say you have sent a bigger data at lower pace, then you found out that you sent way too much data... guess what? recode!